# Unable to run movit

Tags: ros, moveit, acceleration, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I Just Installed ros on ubuntu 14.04 running as a guest on my virtual box(windows as host), by following the guidelines given on the installation page.
After that I installed movit to run pr2 robot on it. on starting the program by following command `roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch`

the process starts and then stops with following error

```
[rviz_project_VirtualBox_2323_7179665185602142764-6] process has died [pid 2384, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rviz/rviz -d /opt/ros/indigo/share/pr2_moveit_config/launch/moveit.rviz __name:=rviz_project_VirtualBox_2323_7179665185602142764 __log:=/home/project/.ros/log/aa7e68a2-3ba9-11e5-825d-08002735575a/rviz_project_VirtualBox_2323_7179665185602142764-6.log].
log file: /home/project/.ros/log/aa7e68a2-3ba9-11e5-825d-08002735575a/rviz_project_VirtualBox_2323_7179665185602142764-6*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215299/unable-to-run-movit./) by [Rishabh Tiwari](https://answers.ros.org/users/23469/rishabh-tiwari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2015-08-05**:
What does the log say? /home/project/.ros/log/aa7e68a2-3ba9-11e5-825d-08002735575a/rviz_project_VirtualBox_2323_7179665185602142764-6*.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Getting any serious 3D accelerated application running in a VM (whether VMware or VirtualBox) is a gamble. RViz is such an application, and while it can probably be done, this site is full of questions and reports of users that have failed.

The PR2 meshes are rather detailed, and I can imagine put quite a strain on any 3D graphics pipeline, and I wouldn't be surprised if the OpenGL implementation of VirtualBox is not capable of supporting it.

That is all assuming that you installed the 3D acceleration extensions and drivers. If you haven't yet, you could try to see whether that makes any difference.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0